# How do I find the index of a substring within a string in Javascript from a position otther than the string start?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to some string manipulation using javascript/jquery.

How do I find the position of a substring within a string starting at a position somewhere in the middle of the string?

Consider the following string:

```
"Item1 100 Item2 200"
```

If I know the index of the starting point of "100" (the position of "1") within the string, how do I find the index of the 1st space which occurs after this?

So what I'm really looking for is the index of the space that occurs before "200".

I know in C#/VB.Net there are robust string libraries which allow me to easily slice and dice the string.

How do I accomplish this using jquery/javascript?

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: the first space after 100 is before 'Item2'?

Comment: What is the end goal? Using `.split(" ")` for instance will return `["Item1", "100", "Item2", "200"]`. (rule of thumb: instead of asking "how do I use Y to accomplish X?", always ask "how do I accomplish X?")

Comment: I googled javascript substring index and the following showed up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: Read the documentation of `indexOf`

Comment: Splice out up to the index you have then `splicedString.indexOf(" ")` will give you the index of the first space. Add the index you spliced up to to get the index in the original string

Answer (score 3):

[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) takes a second parameter indicating where to start. So if you know where you want to start, you can just pass that in:

```js
let s = "Item1 100 Item2 200"
let i100 = 6                   // known index of 100

let ind = s.indexOf(" ", i100) // start looking at 6
console.log(ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"So what I'm really looking for is the index of the space that occurs before "200"."*

If you plan on indexing spaces then referencing the position of 100 should be 3, either way the space after 100 is not the space before 200. Therefore I will accept your second statement as the predicate.

**findSpace(string, term, start, after)**

param 1: **string** to search through
param 2: **term** string to find
param 3: **start** index to start from -- defaults to 0
param 4: **after** find the space after term -- defaults to false

It finds the space before the substring if found and returns the index of the space.

The key to including each space as an array element is to pass a regex that captures whitespace as the delimiter to the `.split((\s))` method. Then use `.indexOf()` method to extract the index of the given term -1.

```js
var string = "Item1 100 Item2 200 Item11 1100 Item32 8010";

function findSpace(string, term, start = 0, after = false) {
  var arrayA = string.split(/(\s)/);
  console.log(arrayA);
  let index = arrayA.indexOf(term, start);
  return after ? index + 1 : index - 1;
}

console.log(findSpace(string, '200', 1, false));
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the returned result `5` and the  `position of a substring` after a given index the OP is looking for? Aren't we looking for `9` here?

Comment: OP seeks the index of spaces not index of a string. *"...looking for is the index of the space that occurs before "200"."*

Comment: Hmm, I read that much differently because of 'So what I'm really looking for is the index of the space that occurs before "200"' The index of that space is `9`. Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: I split the string and kept each space as a separate element and looks like 5?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop with the [indexOf()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-string-prototype-indexof-function/) function if you want to find the indices of all the 'space' instances.

Hope the snippet helps give an idea.

```css
button {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#index {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="find();">
Reveal indices
</button>
<br>
<p id="index"></p>

<script>
  function find() {
    var str = "Item1 100 Item2 200";
    var j = [];
    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
      var n = str.indexOf(" ", i);
      const isInArray = j.includes(n);
      if (!isInArray && n > 0) {
        j.push(n);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = j;
  }

</script>
```